# R plot doesn't work on my Windows, but plot.default does

Tags: r, windows, plot, rstudio

I'm taking a course in R and I've hit a road block on day one.

Typing:

demo(graphics)

...should start a series of graphs being displayed on screen. On my Windows 10 (64 bit) new Dell laptop, I get a persistent error:

[image: Resulting Error in red]

The execution is stopped after the red lines, seemingly because the demo(graphics) call is being made with incompatible parameters. In blue I make the same call but use the default function and an empty plot is displayed.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, installing through Anaconda and from the CRAN website. The same error persists. I've even tried with mro instead of basic R.

I don't see any similar error messages in my class or on Google. My guess is that I need to install a particular version of R and RStudio make it work but I'm guessing.

Can anybody offer some expertise?

I'm running **R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)** (which is executing code correct, just not the demo call) and RStudio Version[image: RStudio Version]

Comment: Try running R without RStudio and see if it works. Go to the Start menu, type "rgui" and click on the app that appears

Comment: The same thing but if I manually input plot.default is plots something, though it looks like a different dataset.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231402/just-started-learning-r-unable-to-render-demographics                                                             Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: can you update your rstudio version to 1.2.1335 (or higher if available)

Comment: @user3535074 I have had a similar issue where plotting was slow and also plotting blanks. A solution that has worked was:
`dev.off() # run multiple times until "null device 1" appears
dev.new() # run once`
PS The code that's giving you trouble worked perfectly for me on R version 3.6.1 and R studio 1.2.5019

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me, though I agree that it's probably the source of the problem. What is your layout? I wonder if customisations to the layout have caused it....

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe helping to narrow it down… It looks like something is causing R to use a different plot method that doesn't accept those two arguments in the error. There's no vector method, so `plot.default()` *should* be used when the `plot()` method is called. Perhaps a stupid question, but is this the first thing you run after opening R/RStudio?

Comment: I've run other r code including visualisation using plot.default and it works as expected. It's just that as 'demo' is the first thing suggested to run, I figure if it isn't working, there will be more problems later on...

Comment: Try running a vanilla version of R.  To do that ensure that Rgui.exe is on the Windows PATH and then from the Windows cmd line run `Rgui --vanilla` and try the code again.  If that fixes it then it's a problem with your .Rprofile file.

Answer (score 0):

Running the basic Rgui software from the command line with the --vanilla parameter like so:

```
Rgui --vanilla
```

Opened Rgui and the

```
demo(graphics)
```

...call worked.

This meant that the issue was in the .Rprofile file. This is found in the etc folder of the basic R installation and when I checked, it looked absolutely fine (entirely commented out actually).

I wanted to use RStudio though, so I investigated the RStudio docs and saw that each project is given its own .Rprofile style initialization file when a new project is created.

So I created a new project with RStudio and by creating a new project whatever configuration issue was causing the error was completely fixed.

Credits to  G. Grothendieck for the answer in the comments.